# Java multithreaded: program sporadically strats using more cores than a FixedThreadPool is allowed to

Tags: java, multithreading, amd-processor

I have an application which just uses **ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool()**, and everything runs fine on our development machines (multicore Intels mostly, also runs fine on a 6 core AMD). But when we run it on our server (Opteron CPUs, 64 cores total) and the thread pool is limited to, say, 4 threads, sporadically something weird happens and the program starts using 48 cores.
There is nothing but a main thread and this **ExecutorService** which should be limited to N threads, so there should be no more than **N+1(main)+X(some java services)** threads, but definitely not 48+.
Any suggestions on what might be causing this behavior are highly appreciated.
I'm not posting any code here, because we were not able to reproduce this in any other environment, than this server and there's nothing special about the code. It's just the fixed thread pool, on which Callables are run in batches (each batch no more than the size of thread pool) and the results are collected from Futures before submitting the next batch of tasks.

Comment: How about GC in the PROD server? How often does this happen? Any correlation to request load or batch processing?

Comment: @prabugp : I just don't see how would GC relate to the problem of a thread pool using more resources, than it should. I just didn't measure any statistics on the server, but what I can say for sure, is that it should not be happening. E.g. the app parses a file (1-2Gb) in a multithreaded manner, and the resulting data structure rarely exceeds 1-2Gb. The server has 64Gb ram, so it should not be the problem, GC probably almost never kicks in there.

Comment: You can probably try using `newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads, ThreadFactory threadFactory` and control the creation of new threads for the ExecutorService.

Comment: Are you sure all the threads are from this app ? When it jumps to 48 how long does it stay there ?

Comment: what's your method for determining that all those threads are from the thread pool and not say the GC? Because, yes the GC (and jit) may definitely spawn additional threads if it want to.

Comment: @Voo : I have no method to determine this. It happens sporadically, it never happens on our dev machines with up to 8 cores. You say it to use 2 threads, then 2 cores are utilized, never does it go to using all 8 physically available ones.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using a parallel garbage collector.  See here: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-gc-dev/2009-January/000718.html

From that answer, it looks like you'll have 40 threads of GC, plus your application threads.  So that's probably what's happening.

Check this out: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html -- in particular set XX:ParallelGCThreads=n

If it helps ... I had this exact same thing happen to me, except the container monitor killed my process for excess thread usage.  Oh HP-UX, how I (don't) miss you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try that today and accept the answer if that works, but I thought that the default was `-XX:-UseSerialGC`, not `-XX:-UseParallelGC`.

Comment: And btw, that's exactly why I noticed this in the first place - our job scheduler (Maui) ran the jobs and a script checked for actual resource usage vs requested resource usage and it just killed those java jobs for no apparent reason. Then I saw that the CPU usage was going through the roof moments before the job was being killed.